# Intuitive Explanation: Topology; Topological Space

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

I am really struggling to understand the concepts of topology and topological spaces. I read so many PDFs, Books, websites but I haven't found an easy intuitive explanation.
For example, if I have all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. What information does the Topology on this set of points add? Is the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ a topological space and if so, is the topological space just the set of points?

I am very confused. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Have you studied metric spaces? You really should study these first. Topological spaces are generalisations of metric spaces. Every metric space induces a topology, but not necessarily vice versa

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose: I shouldn’t be at all surprised if that turned out to be good advice for the OP, but it has its dangers as a general approach: it’s far too easy with that approach for students to get the idea that topological spaces in general behave like metric spaces. I prefer to start with general topological spaces and add structure. If students need a more familiar touchstone, I’d rather introduce linearly ordered spaces in general: they are so obviously not representative that the same problem does not arise.

Comment: I'm no topologist, and perhaps Brian M. Scott will provide or point to a detailed answer, but just a quick comment to the OP: No, a topology is not "just the set of points". It's that, and a collection of subsets called "open", which satisfy the definition of a topology. There can be many different possible topologies on a set, such as $\mathbb{R}^2$, although there is a "usual" topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: One comment: a topological space is the minimal structure needed in order to define and discuss continuous functions. Mathematicians love to use the least restrictive set of assumptions possible when proving their theorems, and this leads them to defining various types of spaces which satisfy various sets of axioms. The axioms are the minimal assumptions they need to develop their theory. A benefit of this approach is that the resulting theory applies not just to $\mathbb R^n$ but also to many less familiar or more exotic settings. But, the axioms might seem strange or abstract at first.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! You are right, that I need more background knowledge but I am actually familiar with metric spaces and do understand the concept behind it. But a topological space just seems so unnatural to me compared to a metric space. I don't get the intuition behind it. But I think I am slowly starting to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $\mathbb{R}^2$ is dust. It has no structure. When we draw it as a plane, we are giving it some sort of geometric structure. (This geometric structure is better described as a metric space than a topology, and even better described as a manifold, but we'll stick with topology for now.)

The idea of mathematics is to give sets structure to capture our intuitive notions about them. $\mathbb{R}^2$ is best thought of as a manifold, though, and not a topological space. Really, the history of it was that first we thought of manifolds--curves and surfaces and so on. And only later on did we abstract away to metric spaces and topologies.

Metric spaces are the first conceptual leap from the concept of a surface. The idea of a metric space is that we can take any set $X$ whatsoever, and equip it with a 'nice' way of measuring the distance between two points in $X.$ These spaces occur all over the place.

A topological space is the next step in generalization. For these, you need to make the leap that a lot of the time, instead of using the metric, you want to talk about these funny open sets when you're working with your metric space. And so this leads to a neat idea: Why not just define the 'visual' structure in terms of the open sets? This leads you to topology. But it's hard to see why such an abstract thing is useful a priori. There are nonmetrizable spaces (ie, topological spaces which cannot be made into metric spaces) people can show you, but I think the most common ones elicit mostly a reaction of "cool, but why would I ever want to study this space?". The true answer to this question is that you really should read a book on geometry and on analysis to learn some of the theory of metric spaces and manifolds, and slowly start to see the utility of the "open set" perspective. Then, come back to studying point-set topology once you find out that you *need* it to do something. That something could be a number of things--maybe you want to work with quotient spaces and are tired of having to deal with metrics all the time; maybe you want to do functional analysis or algebraic geometry and come up against non-metrizable spaces; maybe you want to indulge in the pure abstraction of it for fun once you realize the utility. But please, just dip your toes into geometry and analysis so you know *why* you're doing what you're doing. The first few sections of a point-set topology book will be easy if you can keep the right pictures in your mind (and you'll slowly learn how to refine your mental images to be truer to reality) *if* you know what's going on, but can be a nightmare if you don't.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and intuitive answer!!! I am starting to understand the need for. I am trying to learn about hyperbolic geometry and I actually get most of the key concepts, definition and ideas behind it (at least to the extent, which is sufficient for my project). But I did not understand the key idea behind a Topological Space. You are right, I should work through some literature, just reading definitions after definitions is not enough. Do you probably have some literature recommendations?
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A topological space is a pair $(X,T)$ where $T$ is a collection of some or all of the subsets of X such that

(i). $\emptyset\in T$ and $X\in T,$

(ii). If $S\subset T$ then $\bigcup S\in T,$

(iii). If $S\subset T$ and if $S$ is *finite* then $\bigcap S\in T.$

$T$ is called a topology on $X.$ Members of $T$ are called open sets. If $X$ has more than one member, then whether a subset of $X$ is open or not depends on which $T$ we are considering.

This is very general. Nothing in the definition requires that anything, other than $\emptyset$ and $X,$ belongs to $T.$ Nothing in the def'n prevents $all$ subsets of $X$ from belonging to $T.$

It is very common to refer to "the space $X$" without specifying $T.$ When $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ and $X=\Bbb R^n,$ it is common to assume that $T$ is the "standard" ("usual") topology.

For $x\in X,$ and for a given $T,$ a neighborhood (nbhd) of $x$ is any set $V\subseteq X$ such that there exists $U\in T$ with $x\in U\subseteq V.$